# React JS UseState weekly display headers Time sheet

Tags: react-hooks, react-table, react-datepicker, react-calendar, timesheet.js

I am working on to implement a timesheet component in react using useState.I got bit confused with certain functionalities and how this is working behind the scenes(I am still learn guys).When I click the previousweek or nextweek control buttons, the dates are changing in a random way instead of showing the current month's nextweek dates or previousweek dates.
The other issue also, whenever I I start typing in the inputs the dates on the headers are also changing randomly.

I am missing someting here, Would appreciate for a help out.Thanks

```js
const TimeSheet = () => {

  const days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { project: 'Project A', hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], total: 0 },
    { project: 'Project B', hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], total: 0 },
  ]);

  const handlePreviousWeek = () => {
    // setStartDate(new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7)));

    const prevWeek = new Date(startDate);
    prevWeek.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7);
    setStartDate(prevWeek);
  };

  const handleNextWeek = () => {
    // setStartDate(new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 7)));
    const nextWeek = new Date(startDate);
    nextWeek.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 7);
    setStartDate(nextWeek);
  };

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    setData([
      ...data,
      { project: `Project ${data.length + 1}`, hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], total: 0 },
    ]);
  };

  const handleDeleteRow = (index) => {
    const updatedData = [...data];
    updatedData.splice(index, 1);
    setData(updatedData);
  };

  const handleSaveHours = () => {
    console.log('Hours saved:', data);
  };

  // const calculateTotal = (hours) => {
  //   let total = 0;
  //   for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
  //     total += parseInt(hours[i]) || 0;
  //   }
  //   return total;
  // };

  const handleHoursChange = (projectIndex, dayIndex, value) => {
    const updatedData = [...data];
    updatedData[projectIndex].hours[dayIndex] = value;
    updatedData[projectIndex].total = updatedData[projectIndex].hours.reduce(
      (acc, cur) => acc + cur,
      0
    );
    setData(updatedData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Project Simple Time Sheet</h1>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handlePreviousWeek}>Previous Week</button>
        {/* <span>{startDate.toLocaleDateString("de-DE")}</span> */}
        <span>{`${startDate.toLocaleDateString('de-DE')} - ${new Date(
              startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 6)
            ).toLocaleDateString('de-DE')}`}</span>
        <button onClick={handleNextWeek}>Next Week</button>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Project</th>

            {/* {Array.from({ length: 7 }).map((_, index) => (
              <th key={index}>{new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1)).toLocaleDateString("de-DE")}</th>
            ))} */}

          {days.map((day) => (
                  <th key={day}>
                    {day}
                    <br />
                    {new Date(
                      startDate.getFullYear(),
                      startDate.getMonth(),
                      startDate.getDate() + days.indexOf(day)
                    ).toLocaleDateString('de-DE')}
                  </th>
                ))}
            <th>Total</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{item.project}</td>
              {item.hours.map((hour, dayIndex) => (
                <td key={dayIndex}>
                  <input type="number" value={hour} onChange={(e) => handleHoursChange(index, dayIndex,     e.target.value)} />
                </td>
              ))}
              <td>
                {item.total}
            
              
              </td>
              <td><button onClick={() => handleDeleteRow(index)}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
          ))}
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            {Array.from({ length: 7 }).map((_, index) => <td key={index}></td>)}
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={handleAddRow}>Add Row</button>
      <button onClick={handleSaveHours}>Save Hours</button>
      <button onClick={() => console.log('Hours submitted:', data)}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TimeSheet;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```js
<span>{`${startDate.toLocaleDateString('de-DE')} - ${new Date(
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 6)
    ).toLocaleDateString('de-DE')}`}</span>
```

Basically in `new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 6))` you are calling `startDate.setDate()`, which means you are modifying the internal value of `startDate`, and that is happening in every rendering!. To fix that I recommend using a utility function to offset dates, for example:

```js
const dateOffset = (date, offset) => {
  const newDate = new Date(date);
  newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + offset)
  return newDate;
}
```

Then replace the buggy line with:

```js
<span>{`${startDate.toLocaleDateString('de-DE')} - ${dateOffset(startDate, 6).toLocaleDateString('de-DE')}`}</span>
```

Also, you can use it in `handlePreviousWeek` and `handleNextWeek`:

```js
const handlePreviousWeek = () => {
  setStartDate((currDate) => dateOffset(currDate, -7));
};

const handleNextWeek = () => {
  setStartDate((currDate) => dateOffset(currDate, 7));
};
```

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, thank you so much for your answer, Brilliant!    My following question is this, I want to give the user the chance to add empty sheet as he clicks the nextWeek button like in Pagination for the next page and set the inputs cells empty if they are in the future. Could this be a possibility? )

Comment: There are many ways to get that, but I will suggest including in your project data a new object that stores all the inputs values in a dictionary using the date as key, something like `{'12-12-202': 1, '13-12-2021': 2}`, then just write a function to get and set those values depending on project and week date.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, Thank you once again for your suggesting, I have something like this: 

  const handleSubmit = () => {
        const newSubmission = {
        [new Date(startDate)]: [...data],
        };
        setPreviousSubmissions([...previousSubmissions, newSubmission]);
       console.log(myCurrentActiveProject.length) 
       console.log(myCurrentActiveProject) 
       console.log(dataSet.length) 

      };

Comment: I think that is going in the right direction, but to have more context and be more precise I think it should go to a separate question, and don't forget to mark this as answered.

Comment: Hi @Johathan, I tried few ways using your suggestion above. But I still could not succeed in getting it to write the way. I wonder if you want to take a look at it. I have posted a question with the  link : 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75643813/loading-dataset-base-on-the-start-of-the-week-date-when-the-user-click-the-contr