# Loading dataset base on the start of the week date when the user click the control buttons(previous week / next week weekly calendar controls)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I have timesheet components which loads project list and hours spent on this project.I want to give the user the chance to load the previous week hours for the project added on the Timesheet when he clicks the previous week button and and current week an empty sheet if no hours was saved and also set the week ahead empty because its is in the future.
I have hard coded array of object for testing I am missing some point here with regards to the data defination maybe or the previous week,current week and next wek state variable.
Would appreciate a help out[Timesheet UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWFIL.png)

```
import React from "react";

import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";

const  TimeSheet = () => {
  const customStyles = {
    content: {
      top: '50%',
      left: '50%',
      right: 'auto',
      bottom: 'auto',
      marginRight: '-50%',
      transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    },
  };

  const [weekStartDate, setWeekStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [timeSheetData, setTimeSheetData] = useState({});

  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  const dateOffset = (date, offset) => {
    const newDate = new Date(date);
    newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + offset )
    return newDate;
  }

  const days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];

  let dataSet = [
    { project: 'Project A', hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], total: 0 ,isActive: true },   
    { project: 'Project B', hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], total: 0 ,isActive: true},
    { project: 'Project C', hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], total: 0,isActive: true },
    { project: 'Project D', hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], total: 0 ,isActive: true},
    { project: 'Project E', hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], total: 0 ,isActive: false},
    { project: 'Project F', hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], total: 0 ,isActive: true},
    { project: 'Project G', hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], total: 0,isActive: true},
  ];

  // Function to get timesheet data from local storage
  const getSavedTimeSheetData = () => {
    const savedData = localStorage.getItem(
      `timeSheetData_${weekStartDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)}`
    );
    if (savedData) {
      return JSON.parse(savedData);
    } else {
      return {};
    }
  };

  // Load saved timesheet data on previous week button click if week start date matches
  const loadSavedData = () => {
    const savedData = getSavedTimeSheetData();
    const savedWeekStartDate = savedData.weekStartDate;
    if (savedWeekStartDate && savedWeekStartDate === weekStartDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)) {
      setTimeSheetData(savedData.timeSheetData);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadSavedData();
  }, [weekStartDate]);

   // Function to set timesheet data to local storage
   const saveTimeSheetData = () => {
    const dataToSave = { weekStartDate: weekStartDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10), timeSheetData };
    localStorage.setItem(
      `timeSheetData_${weekStartDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)}`,
      JSON.stringify(dataToSave)
    );
  };

  const myCurrentActiveProject = dataSet.filter(function (activeProject) {
    return activeProject.isActive
  })

  const [data, setData] = useState(() => myCurrentActiveProject);

  const handlePreviousWeek = () => { 
    setStartDate((currDate) => dateOffset(currDate, -7));
  };

  const handleNextWeek = () => {
    setStartDate((currDate) => dateOffset(currDate, 7));

    setData(data.map((data) =>({
      ...data,
      hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         
    })))
  };

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    setData([
      ...data,
      { project: `Project ${data.length + 1}`, hours: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], total: 0 },
    ]);
  };

  const handleDeleteRow = (index) => {
    const updatedData = [...data];
    updatedData.splice(index, 1);
    setData(updatedData);
  };

  const calculateTotal = (hours) => {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
      total += parseInt(hours[i]) || 0;
    }
    return total;
  };
 
  const handleHoursChange = (projectIndex, dayIndex, value) => {
    const updatedData = [...data];
    updatedData[projectIndex].hours[dayIndex] = value;
    updatedData[projectIndex].total =calculateTotal(updatedData[projectIndex].hours);

    setData(updatedData);
    
    console.log('Update as you type', updatedData);

  };

  // const [hours, setHours] = useState({});`

  const handleSaveHours = () => {
    const newSubmission = {
      // date: new Date(startDate),
    [new Date(startDate)]: [...data],
    };
    setPreviousSubmissions([...previousSubmissions, newSubmission]);

    setSavedData([...savedData, newSubmission])
    setTimeSheetData([...timeSheetData, newSubmission])

    console.log("Week start date ",startDate)
    console.log('Hours saved:', newSubmission);
  };

  const [previousSubmissions, setPreviousSubmissions] = useState([]);
  const [savedData,setSavedData] = useState([]);
  const handlePreviousSubmissions = () => {
  console.log(previousSubmissions);
};

  const handleSubmit = () => {
        const newSubmission = {
        
         [new Date(startDate)]: [...data]
        };
        setPreviousSubmissions([...previousSubmissions, newSubmission]);
        setTimeSheetData([...timeSheetData, newSubmission])
        saveTimeSheetData();
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(previousSubmissions));
      }, [previousSubmissions]);

      let subtitle;
  const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  function openModal() {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }

  function afterOpenModal() {
    // references are now sync'd and can be accessed.
    subtitle.style.color = '#f00';
  }

  function closeModal() {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Your Simple Project's Time Management App</h1>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handlePreviousWeek}>Previous Week</button>
       

     <span>{`${startDate.toLocaleDateString('de-DE')} - ${dateOffset(startDate, 6).toLocaleDateString('de-DE')}`}</span>
        <button onClick={handleNextWeek}>Next Week</button>
         
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Project</th>

          {days.map((day) => (
                  <th key={day}>
                    {day}
                    <br />
                    {new Date(
                      startDate.getFullYear(),
                      startDate.getMonth(),
                      startDate.getDate() + days.indexOf(day) 
                    ).toLocaleDateString('de-DE')}
                  </th>
                ))}

            <th>Total</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{item.project}</td>
              {item.hours.map((hour, dayIndex) => (
                <td key={dayIndex}>
                  <input type="number" value={hour} onChange={(e) => handleHoursChange(index, dayIndex, e.target.value)} />
                </td>
              ))}
              <td>
                {item.total}
            
              
              </td>
              <td><button onClick={() => handleDeleteRow(index)}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
          ))}
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            {Array.from({ length: 7 }).map((_, index) => <td key={index}></td>)}
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={handleAddRow}>Add New Project</button>
      <button onClick={handleSaveHours}>Save Hours</button>
      <button onClick={ handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      {/* {previousSubmissions.length > 0 && ( */}
        <button onClick={handlePreviousSubmissions}>
          View previous submissions
        </button>
    

<button onClick={openModal}>Open Modal</button>
      <Modal
        isOpen={modalIsOpen}
        onAfterOpen={afterOpenModal}
        onRequestClose={closeModal}
        style={customStyles}
        contentLabel="Example Modal"
      >
        <h2 ref={(_subtitle) => (subtitle = _subtitle)}>Hello</h2>
        <button onClick={closeModal}>close</button>
        <div>I am a modal</div>
        <form>
          <input />
          <button>tab navigation</button>
          <button>stays</button>
          <button>inside</button>
          <button>the modal</button>
        </form>
      </Modal>

    </div>
  );
};

export default TimeSheet;
```

Comment: It would be great to have the whole component code, the HTML part is half of the story.

Comment: Hello @Jonathan, I have added the whole component. I have some code commented there which I was trying to test locally using local storage. I would be glad to explain if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think saving the hours per each day of the week as an array, increases the complexity and unnecessarily forces to use of additional structures to save other week's data, instead of that I suggest using a different structure, something like:

```json
{
    "project": "Project 1",
    "sheet": {
        "3/7/2023": "1",
        "3/8/2023": "1",
        ...
    }
}
```

Instead of saving the hours per day of the week, just save the hours per date, then we can just create a user interface that deals with that dates showing them grouped in weeks, here is a prototype of that:

```js
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";

const dateOffset = (date, offset) => {
  const newDate = new Date(date);
  newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + offset);
  return newDate;
};

const getFirstDayOfWeek = (date) => {
  const day = (date.getDay() + 6) % 7; // Monday is the first day of week
  return dateOffset(date, -day);
};

const weekDayFormat =  {weekday: 'short', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'};

export const TimeSheet = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(getFirstDayOfWeek(new Date()));
  const isFutureStartDate = useMemo(() => startDate > new Date(), [startDate]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { project: "Project 1", sheet: {} },
    { project: "Project 2", sheet: {} },
  ]);

  const handlePreviousWeek = () => {
    setStartDate((currDate) => dateOffset(currDate, -7));
  };

  const handleNextWeek = () => {
    setStartDate((currDate) => dateOffset(currDate, 7));
  };

  const getValue = (index, date) => {
    const key = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US');
    return data[index].sheet[key] ?? "";
  };

  const setValue = (index, date, value) => {
    const key = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US');
    setData((prevData) => {
      const newData = [...prevData];
      if (value === "") delete newData[index].sheet[key]; // remove key if empty
      else newData[index].sheet[key] = value;
      return newData;
    });
  };

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    setData([
      ...data,
      {
        project: `Project ${data.length + 1}`,
        sheet: {},
      },
    ]);
  };

  const handleDeleteRow = (index) => {
    setData((prevData) => {
      const updatedData = [...prevData];
      updatedData.splice(index, 1);
      return updatedData
    });
  };

  const getTotal = (index, dates) => {
    return dates.reduce((total, date) => {
      const val = 1 * getValue(index, date);
      return total + val
    }, 0);
  };

  const weekDates = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, i) =>
    dateOffset(startDate, i)
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handlePreviousWeek}>Previous Week</button>
        {` ${weekDates[0].toLocaleDateString('en-US')} - ${weekDates[6].toLocaleDateString('en-US')} `}
        <button onClick={handleNextWeek}>Next Week</button>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Project</th>
            {weekDates.map((day) => (
              <th key={day}>
                {day.toLocaleDateString('en-US', weekDayFormat)}
              </th>
            ))}
            <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{item.project}</td>
              {weekDates.map((date) => (
                <td key={date}>
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    value={getValue(index, date)}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      setValue(index, date, e.target.value)
                    }
                    disabled={isFutureStartDate}
                  />
                </td>
              ))}
              <td>{getTotal(index, weekDates)}</td>
              <td><button onClick={() => handleDeleteRow(index)}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
          ))}
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            {weekDates.map((day) => (
              <th key={day}>
                {day.toLocaleDateString('en-US', weekDayFormat)}
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={handleAddRow}>Add New Project</button>

      {/* Just for visualization purposes */}
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is just a very basic prototype, here is a [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-playground-practice-seassr?file=timesheet.js), and here is it [running](https://react-playground-practice-seassr.stackblitz.io).

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, thank you so much for such a wonderful craft, the structure above makes my life much easier. What would be your advice on the best way to write this data to a database through an API end point when the user hit a saved button and also have the state persist even on page refresh or logout and login? Ya, also the use of Memo functions is awesome, can it be reverse when the user navigate 3 weeks back have inputs disabled? Thank you so much!

Comment: To persist the data locally you can continue using the local storage, maybe just using a `useEffect` to save the `data` every time it changes, maybe you will need to use a **debounce** function if the data changes too fast but probably will not be required. The idea is, when you load the component for the first time, populate the `data` from the local storage. Now, for persisting the `data` in a database with an API, you can do something similar, just send the whole `data` and do the magic in the backend. About the Memo function,  check that the `startDate` is in a range instead of the future.

Comment: Hi @Johnathan, thank you so much for the suggestions on this one,really appreciated !